# Prevent MacOS from showing the accent selection popup in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I'm developing a Flutter desktop app and I have to process raw keyboard input (custom drawn control that handles user input).

For this I'm using a `TextInputClient` and a `TextInputConfiguration` that gets registered via `TextInput.attach(client, config)`.

I have everything working but when I long-press a key on MacOS then I receive one key press and then MacOS shows the accent selection popup.

Is there any way to prevent MacOS from doing that? I tried all different variations of `TextInputConfiguration` parameters but MacOS doesn't care.

The text handling is too much code to paste it here but when needed or not obvious I can create a small sample that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after digging though the internet I found a solution.
I let it here so that other people can find it, too.

The solution is an application wide setting. I didn't find a solution to enable / disable that behaviour on a TextInput instance base.

In the end it comes down to setting a preference for your application that you don't want the tap-and-hold but the auto repeat behaviour.

You can do that in the MacOS integration layer of your Flutter application:

```
AppDelegate.swift
```

Add the following method to the already existing AppDelegate:

```
override func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "ApplePressAndHoldEnabled");
}
```

And that's all.